# Return value from curl array

Tags: php, arrays, api

I have set up a curl to return some values however i'm unsure how to retrieve child values. When i try to retrieve **$bankname** it's empty because its a child value i believe.

```
$bin = "492182";
$url = "https://lookup.binlist.net/" . $bin;
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$resp = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$details = json_decode($resp, true);
$cardscheme = strtoupper($details['scheme']);
$cardtype = ucwords($details['type']);
$cardbrand = ucwords($details['brand']);
$bankname = strtoupper($details['bank']); //<<< need this value
```

Below is the api:

```
    curl / https
    curl -H "Accept-Version: 3" "https://lookup.binlist.net/45717360"
    {
      "number": {
        "length": 16,
        "luhn": true
      },
      "scheme": "visa",
      "type": "debit",
      "brand": "Visa/Dankort",
      "prepaid": false,
      "country": {
        "numeric": "208",
        "alpha2": "DK",
        "name": "Denmark",
        "emoji": "",
        "currency": "DKK",
        "latitude": 56,
        "longitude": 10
      },
      "bank": {
        "name": "Jyske Bank",
        "url": "www.jyskebank.dk",
        "phone": "+4589893300",
        "city": "Hjørring"
      }
    }
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: try $details['bank']['name']

Comment: worked like a charm! thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Sfili comment, if you want the bank name use this example:

```
$s = '{"type":"debit", "brand": "Visa_Dankort", "bank": {"name": "Jyske Bank", "url": "www.jyskebank.dk"}}';
$details = json_decode($s, true);
echo $details["bank"]["name"];
```

This will output: `Jyske Bank`.

You are unable to get this line `$bankname = strtoupper($details['bank']);` because `$details['bank']` is an array and `strtoupper` expecting string.

If I understand your meaning just do: `$bankname = strtoupper($details['bank']['name']);`